# @classmethod y @property en python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo una duda con los decoradores @property y @classmethod, generalmente uso self ( por convención ) y uso el decorador @staticmethod. Así que les agradecería que me explicaran el uso de @classmethod a través de un ejemplo, para poder guiarme con ello e implementarlo en mis programas, ya que no le veo ninguna utilidad (debe tenerla claro) y es por eso que he venido aquí para que me expliquen esa utilidad.

Por otra parte en cuanto a @property, he buscado en linea y no me ha quedado del todo claro, agradecería que me explicaran con sus palabras el uso de este decorador.

Pregunta final (property desde una clase y no una instancia)

p = Padre("melon",9)

print(Hijo.peso)
salida =  property object at 0x016D6150

print(p.peso)
salida = 9

```
@classmethod
def public(self):
    @property
    def peso(self):
        # return sum(cosa.peso for cosa in self.contenido)
           pass
    return sum(cosa.peso for cosa in self.contenido)
```

Con este código si me da el resultado cuando llamo al atributo desde la clase:

print(Hijo.peso)
salida =  9

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Igual son dos preguntas, porque no guardan mucha relación, salvo que ambos son decoradores para métodos...

## `@classmethod`

Este decorador hace que la siguiente función que se declare reciba como primer parámetro la clase, en lugar del objeto. Por convención, en este caso, a ese primer parámetro se le llama `cls`, pero realmente lo puedes llamar como quieras.

Ejemplo:

```
class Ejemplo:
    @classmethod
    def metodo(cls, parametro):
        print("Invocado el classmethod de la clase {}, con parámetro {}".format(cls, parametro))
```

Ahora puedes hacer:

```
>>> Ejemplo.metodo(23)
Invocado el classmethod de la clase <class '__main__.Ejemplo'>, con parámetro 23
```

y ves cómo en el parámetro `cls` ha recibido la clase.

¡Pero para esto no hacía falta este decorador! Siempre que haces `NombreDeClase.metodo()` el método recibirá como primer parámetro el nombre de la clase.

Efectivamente, pero es que gracias a `@classmethod` también puedes invocarlo sobre una instancia, y aún así no recibirá una referencia al objeto, sino a su clase. Mira:

```
>>> ej = Ejemplo()
>>> ej.metodo(23)
Invocado el classmethod de la clase <class '__main__.Ejemplo'>, con parámetro 23
```

Esto es todo lo que hace este decorador. En cuanto a casos de ejemplo en que sean necesarios, la verdad no se me ocurren. Así como un `@staticmethod` es útil para tener un método que no reciba el objeto como parámetro (lo que en realidad podría implementarse en forma de función global, fuera de cualquier clase, pero puede quedar más limpio meterlo de una clase con la que esté relacionado semánticamente), en cambio el caso en que lo que quieras recibir sea la clase a que pertenece un objeto no lo veo tan claro.

Supongo que su aplicación más habitual podría ser para implementar *factorías* que generan objetos de un cierto tipo, a partir de otro objeto de ese tipo, ya que cuando hagas `objeto.metodo()`, ese método recibirá como parámetro la clase del objeto en su parámetro `cls`, por lo que si hace `cls()` podrá instanciar otro objeto de esa misma clase.

## `@property`

Esto es para crear propiedades (atributos que en realidad no existen, sino que se simulan mediante la ejecución de una función)

Aquí sí puedo darte un ejemplo claro. Imagina que tienes un objeto que almacena una lista de cosas, cada una con un peso:

```
class Cosa:
   def __init__(self, nombre, peso):
      self.nombre = nombre
      self.peso = peso


class Mochila:
   def __init__(self, cosas):
       self.contenido = cosas

cosas = [
  Cosa("bocadillo", 200),
  Cosa("cantimplora", 800),
  Cosa("piedra", 300)
]

saco = Mochila(cosas)
```

y que quieres que la mochila te pueda decir cuánto peso lleva. Una solución típica sería implementarle un método:

```
def Mochila:
   ...
   def get_peso(self):
      return sum(cosa.peso for cosa in self.contenido)
```

Efectivamente `saco.get_peso()` nos devolvería 1300 en el ejemplo anterior.

Pues bien, el decorador `@property` te permite dar la apariencia a los usuarios de que el peso es una propiedad más de la mochila (un atributo), cuando en realidad tal atributo no existe sino que es computado por una función. En lugar del método `get_peso()` antes visto, implementarías esto otro:

```
class Mochila:
   ...
   @property
   def peso(self):
       return sum(cosa.peso for cosa in self.contenido)
```

Y ahora puedes hacer `print(saco.peso)`. Observa que no estoy invocando la función, sino accediendo a ella como si fuera un atributo, y pese a todo la función se ejecutará y obtendré el resultado 1300.

Es más, no puedes asignar nada a ese atributo, ya que al haber implementado sólo un método para consultarlo pero no otro para cambiarlo, la propiedad es de sólo lectura:

```
>>> saco.peso = 20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Mediante un *setter* puedes permitir que se cambie el valor de una propiedad, pero en realidad lo que ocurrirá será que se ejecutará tu función setter, en vez de asignarse directamente. Esto te permite, desde esa función, inspeccionar qué valor se le intenta asignar para corregirlo si es erróneo o rechazarlo con una excepción, o ignorarlo, o lo que necesites hacer. Por ejemplo:

```
class Mochila:
    def __init__(self, cosas):
        self.contenido = cosas

    @property
    def peso(self):
      return sum(cosa.peso for cosa in self.contenido)

    @peso.setter
    def peso(self, valor):
        print("Pues no, no cambio el peso al valor {}".format(valor))
```

Y si ahora intentamos cambiar el valor de `saco.peso`, en vez de generarse una excepción se ejecutará el setter:

```
>>> saco.peso = 20
Pues no, no cambio el peso al valor 20
>>> saco.peso
1300
```

Comment: Jamas en la vida habia visto ese @ something.setter, me imagino que habra otro como @ something.setter, verdad?

Comment: Supongo que quieres decir getter. Pero no, el getter es el método tras `@property` No hay un `@peso.getter`, sólo el setter (que sólo puede aparecer después de haber declarado el otro con `@property`, y debe tener el mismo nombre)

Comment: Algo que no me quedo claro, es que dices que mediante un setter se  puede cambiar el valor, pero en realidad lo que estas haciendo, es manejando una excepción , no permitiendo que este atributo invisible cambie. Entonces a fin de cuentas ese atributo invisible no puede ser cambiado?

Comment: No, no... lo que escribí es solo un ejemplo (seguramente no muy bien elegido). No se trata de manejar ninguna excepción, sino que cuando el usuario intenta `saco.peso = 20`, Python en realidad llamará a `saco.peso(20)` (siendo `peso()` en este caso el método declarado tras el decorador `@peso.setter`). Lo que haga ese método es elección tuya. Puede guardar el parámetro recibido en algún atributo del objeto, comprobando antes si está dentro de algunos límites que tal vez quieras imponer, etc. Este método puede elevar una excepción, o no hacer nada de lo anterior (como es el caso de mi ejemplo).

Comment: Una ultima cosa, si ves de nuevo la pregunta veras que puse un código muy raro, y es que tu decorador @property trabaja sobre una instancia y no una clase, y yo intentando que funcionara sin instanciar, hice esto. (creo que es mejor instanciar, esto no es legible).

Comment: No entiendo el código que has añadido. A primera vista diría que está mal indentado. Al menos el `@classmethod` lo está, por lo que ya no me fío del resto. Además ¿dónde está el resto de la clase? No veo claro qué está dentro de qué y no entiendo tampoco lo que dices de que funcione sin instanciar.

Comment: Si esta mal indentado el @ classmethod, osea el @ property funciona desde una instancia de objeto, no desde una clase directamente. Cuando intente llamarlo desde la clase me apareció esto "<property object at 0x016D6150>", y cuando lo hago desde la instancia me sale el resultado con normalidad. Mira de nuevo el problema.

Comment: Sí, ya entiendo, pero eso da para otra pregunta. Ya esta mezcló dos cosas... Creo que la nueva pregunta sería" ¿Se puede usar `@property` para una propiedad de clase?" No conviene andar extendiendo una pregunta ya hecha con preguntas nuevas.